# In which order service listener methods are called when the "kernel.request" event is fired?

Tags: symfony

If I have 2 services like `ServiceName1` and `ServiceName2` with `tag:'kernel.event_listener'` and `event: kernel.request'` in Symfony, in which order will that service methods be called when the `kernel.request` event is fired and priority not set for these services?

Comment: Strictly speaking all listeners have a priority regardless of it is explicitly set. Listeners with the same priority are called in the order in which they are added to the event manager.    But life is too short to worry about such things.  Set the priority and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which the listeners are called should follow the same order as they are written in the service file, like `service.yml` for example, or the order in which the service files were loaded (*if these services they were not written in the same file*).

You should see the same order looking at the "Events" panel of the Symfony profiler, under the "Called Listeners" tab, that includes a list of registered event listeners with their priority.

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony <3.0 from your command line type

```
php app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request
```

for Symfony >3.0 use

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request
```

and it will display a list of registered event listeners and the priority they will fire in.